# Zoom Control is not working for map

Tags: android, zooming, webviewclient

I am having the webview in my application, and i will be getting the data for that webview dynamically, I am having the zoom in control for that view. 
zoom in control is appearing when i get this url http://content.vaayoo.com/AppsPlatForm/DealsaheadWeb/m_facebooks.aspx?Token=moc.liamg@liahs.
but when i get the below url 
https://maps.google.com/?saddr=12.9302,77.5831&daddr=12.928464,77.584258, zoom control is not appearing. what excatly is the problem? any kind of help is highly appreciated..
below is my code..

```
 protected void applyStyles() {

    // applying the zooming property to webview.
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.TOP);

    View zoom = ((WebView) view).getZoomControls();
    FrameLayout ContentView = (FrameLayout) ((Activity) context)
            .getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    ContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Below is the code where i am doing all the setting for webview..

```
if (data != null && webview != null) {
        String webData = data.toString();
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        //webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);


        webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }

                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("webdata" +  webData);
        if (webData.startsWith("http")) {
            webview.loadUrl(webData);



        } else {
            webview.loadData(webData, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }           
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you not using mapview?

Answer (score 2):

if you are having the webview so you have to enable these properties of zoom for webview like this-

```
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

After this the default zoom functionality with be shown to you,i hope this suggestion will be helpful for you.
thanks

Comment: hey dainel, i have enabled these setting. but still not able to see the zoom in controls..

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting `setJavaScriptEnabled` to true. You can also achieve it by

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also check that following properties of `WebView` is present

```
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```